# Returning ASCII codes for strings in a list

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I'm trying to write code that accepts a list of strings and returns a dictionary containing the strings as keys and a list of corresponding character codes as values. I'm using dictionary comprehension and this is what i have.

```
def get_code(words): 
    ascii = {} 
    ascii = [[ord(ch) for ch in word] for word in words]
    return ascii
```

After testing with

```
words = ['yes','no'], i get [[121, 101, 115], [110, 111]]  as the output. 
This {'yes': [121, 101, 115], 'no': [110, 111]} is what i want to get.
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try a dictionary comprehension instead:

```
def get_code(words): 
    ascii = {word: [ord(ch) for ch in word] for word in words}
    return ascii
```

Naturally, you cannot expect to get a dictionary from a list comprehension :)

Comment: Thanks AFetter, this works really perfectly. I should not confuse this again.